# How to assign specific permission to user "nobody" of php in linux?

Tags: linux, php, xampp

I want to make an online judge for c programs. I captured user input in a textarea and made .c file from it. Now it want php to run linux command `gcc code.c

I did it as

```
$cmd=gcc -std=c99 code.c -g -Wall

$last=exec($cmd,$out,$status);
```

as suggested at stackoverflow.
But this command does not work. It returned with status 1. But the other linux commands like date,pwd,etc are working fine.

The problem whic I suspect is that the `whoami` command says "nobody". Now, this "nobody" may not be having permission to run gcc. So, please tell me how to make it work or how to assign permission to user "nobody"?

I know that it s highly insecure. But let it be. Please give solutions to make the command work.

Comment: You shouldn't just take peoples code from a text input box, compile it and execute. This is a security nightmare, its insane.

Comment: Ya I Know, I want to do it only for my own purpose.

Answer (score 11):

1. ***NO***
   You don't use `nobody`. `nobody` should never be used for anything.  `nobody` is an unperson.
   Using `nobody` to do things means granting `nobody` permissions.  Once you do that you start down the slippery slope, and eventually you wind up with `nobody` being a member of the `wheel` group and `su`ing to root because it's just easier, and then your system is pwned by alien space hackers and the entire planet falls and it's ***ALL YOUR FAULT***.
2. ***NO***
   You don't just take other people's code and execute it.
   You don't even take *your own code* and execute it.
   Executing untrusted user input is ***Bad And Wrong***.
   If you want to do this you spin up fully isolated virtual machines to compile and execute the program in a totally isolated sandbox with no network connectivity and no access to the outside machine.

If someone on Stack Overflow implied that this was in any way shape or form a *Good Idea* that person is an idiot. This is why we don't let developers manage production environments.

Comment: I know its a security nightmare. But I just want to do it for my own purpose. So please help me

Comment: @CodeMad I am helping you. Not to be too blunt about it, but if you want to do something *this egregiously bad* and you don't know how to do it you've no business attempting it. You can easily research the things preventing your code from working on your own, and maybe what you discover doing that research will lead you to enlightenment since clearly just being told isn't working...

Answer (score 2):

Stop, do not pass go, do not collect Internet Herpes.

Please, please, please go investigate [Docker](https://www.docker.io/) and learn why something like that is a better solution for this problem.

Comment: Good general idea, but even Docker isn't isolated enough for what he wants to do. This calls for full virtual machines, not just containers, and carefully isolated ones at that.